# pymongo - "dnspython" module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:// URIs

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to connect MongoDB from Atlas.

My **mongo uri** is: `mongodb+srv://abc:123@something.something.com/admin?retryWrites=True`

My **pymongo version** is `3.6.1`

I have installed `dnspython` and done `import dns`

But i still get this error:

> dnspython module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:// URI

Comment: I would need to rephrase my question. I somehow manage to resolve this myself by restarting the kernel of my jupyter notebook.

Comment: you must use `mongo://` instead of `mongodb+srv://`

Answer (score 127):

In order to use **mongo+srv** protocol, you need to install **pymongo-srv**
Launch this command to do it with python 3:

```
pip3 install pymongo[srv]
```

or this one for other versions:

```
pip install pymongo[srv]
```

And as suggested by @lukrebs, add quotes for **ZSH**:

```
pip3 install 'pymongo[srv]'
```

Comment: for those who are using macos and zsh and are getting `zsh: no matches found: pymongo[srv]`, may try `pip3 install 'pymongo[srv]'`

Comment: What would be the syntax for `poetry`?

Comment: For poetry it would be extras: `poetry add pymongo -E srv`

Answer (score 24):

I would like to answer my own questions here. As I mentioned in the comment, the kernel of the jupyter notebook has to be restarted in order for the pymongo to take effect of the loaded `dnspython`.

Comment: the error went away after i did this in command line "pip install dnspython==1.15.0"

Comment: that was my problem! thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I solved this problem with:

`$ python -m pip install pymongo[srv]`

Comment: For python3 users,the  following is useful as well:

`python3-m pip install pymongo[srv]`

Comment: If use zsh, your command must be `python3 -m pip install 'pymongo[srv]'`.

Answer (score 12):

I got stuck with the same problem and tried

`pip install dnspython==2.0.0`

This is the latest version from `https://pypi.org/project/dnspython/`

It worked :D

Comment: dnspython==2.0.0 also worked for me even though it did not work with pymongo[tls,srv] and dnspython==1.16.0.

Comment: You saved me. Thanks.

Comment: worked for me with MongoDB Atlas connection and Python 3.11. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

In requirements.txt, replace `pymongo` with `pymongo[tls,srv]`, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/getredash/redash/issues/2603).

Answer (score 5):

you can use `mongo://` instead of `mongodb+srv://`

Comment: I don't think older version of mongo support replicas. If you use `mongo://`, final URI will be `mongo://db-part-0.host.com:27017, db-part-1.host.com:27017, db-part-2.host.com:27017`. Yes, there is comma in the URI.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found the following line.

```
import dns.resolver
dns.resolver.default_resolver=dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)
dns.resolver.default_resolver.nameservers=['8.8.8.8']
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

May be the protocol, your URI should start with:

**mongo+srv** instead of mongo+src

If it still not working please put a pip list with the versions of PyMongo and dnspython (and version of python that you are using)

Comment: there is no such thing as `mongo+srv` there is `mongodb+srv`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18 but since I am using Anaconda
I just tried

```
Conda install dns python
```

I had an IPython running, it did not work while the same instance was open but when I restarted that instance it worked.

On a different machine using

```
Conda install dns python
```

and it worked but I had to restart my machine altogether due to a different reason before testing it

Comment: I think the command should be corrected as `conda install dnspython` (note that there's no space between dns and python). The library name is `dnspython`. And, for conda, this is the way to go. There's no installation called `pymongo[srv]` when you are in conda...

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install dnspython
```

dnspython is a DNS toolkit for Python. It supports almost all record types. It can be used for queries, zone transfers, and dynamic updates. It supports TSIG authenticated messages and EDNS0.

Answer (score 0):

None of the existing answers had worked for me. I had to do the following:

`sudo apt-get install python3-dnspython`