# ConfigError "dnspython must be installed" when requirement already satisfied

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, mongodb-atlas

Trying to connect a Colab Notebook to a MongoDB on Atlas.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
uri = "mongodb+srv://MYUSERNAME:mypassword@mydatabase.mongodb.net/test"  

client = MongoClient(uri)
```

I am getting a CongfigurationError:

```
"dnspython" module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:// URIs.
```

I installed the module.

```
pip install dnspython
```

Got the message back

```
Requirement already satisfied: dnspython in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.16.0)
```

Do not know what is wrong.

This worked a few days ago with another colab notebook (and another database).

Here is the entire error message:

```
ConfigurationError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-a6c89e14e64f> in <module>()
----> 1 client = MongoClient(uri)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py in __init__(self, host, port, document_class, tz_aware, connect, type_registry, **kwargs)
    522         for entity in host:
    523             if "://" in entity:
--> 524                 res = uri_parser.parse_uri(entity, port, warn=True)
    525                 seeds.update(res["nodelist"])
    526                 username = res["username"] or username

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py in parse_uri(uri, default_port, validate, warn)
    316     elif uri.startswith(SRV_SCHEME):
    317         if not _HAVE_DNSPYTHON:
--> 318             raise ConfigurationError('The "dnspython" module must be '
    319                                      'installed to use mongodb+srv:// URIs')
    320         is_srv = True

ConfigurationError: The "dnspython" module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:// URIs
```

Comment: did the above got resolved !! I am in same situation using collab

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57907815/8718377

Answer (score 21):

You have to restart runtime to have the changes take effect:

1. `!pip install dnspython`
2. Restart runtime `Runtime -> Restart runtime...`
3. Run your code

Answer (score 2):

Try installing pymongo[srv] and [tls]

`!pip3 install pymongo[srv]
!pip3 install pymongo[tls]`

Answer (score 0):

change `mongodb+srv://` to `mongodb://` and it will work