# Any idea why I would get "name 'sys' is not defined" after creating a new MongoClient object in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, sys

I'm working on a Discord bot that saves some data to a mongodb database in response to some user commands. The weird thing is it works on repl.it, but I get this error on SparkedHost. I'm getting an odd error when I create a new MongoClient Object. The server has Python3 3.6.15 installed.  The traceback looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", 
line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/container/main.py", line 36, in listMyWants
await botcommandscontroller.listWants(ctx, ctx.author.id)
File "/home/container/botcommandscontroller.py", line 10, in listWants
wants = mongodbcontroller.getWants(targetID)
File "/home/container/mongodbcontroller.py", line 17, in getWants
cluster = MongoClient(os.getenv('MONGOCONNECT'))
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 
712, in __init__
srv_max_hosts=srv_max_hosts,
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 
467, in parse_uri
python_path = sys.executable or "python"
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

Here's my getWants method:

```
def getWants(userID):
    load_dotenv()
    cluster = MongoClient(os.getenv('MONGOCONNECT'))
    wantcollection = pokedb["wants"]
    userWants = ""
    pipeline = [{'$lookup':
                {'from': 'pokemon',
                'localField': 'dexnum',
                'foreignField': 'NUMBER',
                'as': 'userwants'}},
               {'$unwind': '$userwants'},
               {'$match':
               {'discord_id': userID}}]
    for doc in (wantcollection.aggregate(pipeline)):
        if doc['shiny']:
            userWants += "shiny "
        userWants += doc['userwants']['NAME'] + ", "
    if len(userWants) > 2:
        userWants = userWants[0:len(userWants) - 2]
    return userWants
```

This method probably doesn't have any relevant info, but here's listWants:

```
async def listWants(ctx, targetID):
    if targetID is None:
        await ctx.send(Constants.ErrorMessages.NO_USER_FOUND)
        return
    wants = mongodbcontroller.getWants(targetID)
    if wants != "":
        await ctx.send(wants)
    else:
        await ctx.send(Constants.ErrorMessages.NO_WANTS_FOUND)
```

Comment: Add `import sys` to your code. One host may be adding it for you the other may not be.

Comment: The error appeared to be coming from pymongo. I think I solved it though. I noticed there was some packages that Repl.it installed for me automatically when I installed pymongo that are missing from my SparkedHost server.
dnspython and Flask were missing, and installing those fixed my issue.

Answer (score 5):

I've experienced this when I use pymongo 4.xx version and I solved it by uninstalling pymongo then I try
`pip3 install 'pymongo[srv]'`

It works for me for connection string in `'mongodb+srv://....'` format.

More info for the pymongo installation [pymongo - "dnspython" module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:// URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52930341/pymongo-dnspython-module-must-be-installed-to-use-mongodbsrv-uris)

Answer (score 1):

I guess I should have been more careful about checking my dependencies. Repl.it installed pymongo dependencies that SparkedHost didn't, I think.

Installing dnspython and Flask solved my issue.

Also, I noticed I forgot
pokedb = cluster["pokemon"]
in getWants.