# Pymongo Invalid URI scheme: URI must begin with 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://'

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-functions, pymongo

I am using the latest version of Pymongo `4.3.3` and my connection string looks like below -

`mongodb://userName:password@server:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&socketTimeoutMS=360000&connectTimeoutMS=360000&appName=myAppName`

I use this connection string to connect to the *Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB* using the below code -

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient(connString)
```

I intermittently see the error

```
InvalidURI: Invalid URI scheme: URI must begin with 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://'
```

I have tried `import dns` but not sure how do I use it to resolve this error.
My connection string is correct and when I run it from my local it runs successfully. This intermittently fails when run from *Azure Function App*.

My `requirements.txt` -

```
azure-functions
pymongo
pyodbc
dnspython
```

Can someone please help?
Thank you!

Sanket Kelkar

Comment: Most likely variable `connString` does not hold the connection string you show. Try `print(connString)` to verify.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit
Here's the print output- 
```mongodb://userName:password@server:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&socketTimeoutMS=360000&connectTimeoutMS=360000&appName=myAppName```

I had mistakenly put ```appName=@myAppName@``` in my question (now edited).
it is actually ```appName=myAppName```

Comment: Does your password (or username) has any special characters? Like `: / ? # [ ] @`

Comment: Username no, the password contains a couple of ```=```s.

Comment: Can you check this? Is it helpful to use ```pymongo[tls,srv]``` instead of ```pymongo```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53644085/11163817
I have already tried this and it ran a couple of times successfully, but can I consider it a permanent solution?

Comment: Hi @Wernfried Domscheit, can you please help if you know of any workaround? Thanks!

Comment: According documentation `=` should be no problem. However, try to [encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting) the password and username.